# What is the difference between RKHS inner product and a "regular" inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I have a book (http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/) that has in the notation section...

$$
\langle f, g \rangle_\mathcal{H} = \text{RKHS inner product} \\
\|f\|_\mathcal{H} = \text{RKHS norm}
$$

How are these different than the inner product of vectors $x^Tx$ and the L2 norm $\|x\|^2$ that uses the same notation without the $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: From what I remember, a RKHS has an evaluation functional, by the Riesz theorem any functional can be represented as inner product. There's no "difference" except for the assumption of the existence of such functional, which can be expressed using the inner product.

Comment: The way you have currently written it there is not that much difference other than the fact that an RKHS is a Hilbert space of functions and so an inner product may look like $\langle f,g\rangle =  \int f(x)g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ rather than $x^Tx$.

The notation $\mathcal{H}$ in $\langle f,g \rangle_\mathcal{H}$ is just specifying that we are taking the inner product in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: @user8469759 well every Hilbert space of functions has a linear evaluation functional, it’s the boundedness, or equivalently the continuity, of the evaluation functional that makes it an RKHS.

Comment: Nobody knows what RKHS and ${\cal H}$ are. Wait until these notations are actually used in context, and make the most natural assumptions about their meaning.

Comment: @adfriedman what's the construction of such a functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H$ is a real separable Hilbert space with a Gaussian measure $\mu$, then its covariance operator $S$ is positve, selfadjoint and of finite trace. Since the topological support of a Gaussian measure is a linear subvariety, we can consider the support of $\mu
$.
The topological support of $\mu$ is the closure of the linear span of the eigenvalues of $S$. The restriction makes $S$ injective on the support.

Now $\sqrt{S}$ exists, is positive, selfadjoint, Hilbert Schmidt and $\sqrt{S}(H)$ is dense in $H$. We define in $\sqrt{S}(H)$ the inner product
$$\langle \sqrt{S}x,\sqrt{S}y\rangle_0=\langle x,y\rangle_H.$$
which makes $\sqrt{S}H$ into a Hilbert space with $\sqrt{S} :H\to 
\sqrt{S}(H)$ an isometric isomorphism. The space $\sqrt{S}H$ is the reproducing kernel Hilbert space of $(H,\mu)$.

"How are these different?" This depends on the Hilbert space you're working with. If you're working with a non degenerate Gaussian measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the RKHS is the entire space. If you're working with the Frechet space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, the space is $\ell^2$ with the usual $\ell^2$ norm.

Comment: Is there a standard reference for this?